# HDMI to VGA adapter power

Tags: power, hdmi, display

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B, and I would like to plug it in a VGA computer monitor. I have been reading about this subject, but I am no expert in electronics, and so I am afraid I might end up being one of those cases where the Pi components burn.

The Pi's power adapter is a 5V 1200mA, and I have a dongle type HDMI to VGA adapter, as seen in the [forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=83446) (search for the text "dongle" and you'll get right to the picture). This adapter claims to be a 5V 200mA adapter.

Given that the Pi's D1 diode has a safe limit of 200mA output, is it safe to use this adapter, or am I still subject to risk and luck?

---

The Pi grabs 500mA for itself, the HDMI adapter grabs another 200mA, and I intend to connect a 100mA keyboard, yielding a total of 800mA, which should still be in the safe 1A limit the Pi can handle. Besides that, I think I would occasionally plug in a USB pen drive to save my work.

Comment: I went ahead and tried it myself. No smoke so far, everything works fine, with the tweaks I've found elsewhere for the config.txt file. Still, I am interested in answers from someone who knows better than I do.

Answer (score -1):

I have read your description and It sounds that I would be careful about what you use, as this may seem mathematically correct the board may have some exceptions, and also It depends on the Usb drive is capable of taking when download data from the pi. I would see if there are any other cables like this [HDMI TO VGA CABLE](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HDMI-to-VGA-Adapter-/121715118482?hash=item1c56c95192)

Comment: The adapter you linked is very similar to mine. The difference is that mine didn't say anywhere it had been tested with Raspberry, but it was quite more expensive, so I expect a trustworthy product.

Comment: Many people have good experience with $3 HDMI to VGA adapters, so more expensive doesn't always mean better quality.