# Pi-4 and going into weird video mode

Tags: raspbian, video, pi-4

I recently purchased my Pi-4 and am quite impressed with the performance. However, I'm also noticing a problem after the board has been running for a little while. Initially, everything is beautiful, but after a while it begins to have this weird video behavior. This is what the screen looks like:

[image: Pi-4 video problem]

I've installed some cheap heat sinks on the board and have it in the case with the top off. I'm running stock Raspbian and am using an official power supply.

The guys I bought it from said that they don't know if this is a hardware problem. The device is so new, that they're still learning about the problems and didn't want to say that it's replaceable until others spoke up.

Is this a replaceable problem, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what resolution are you running? What GPU memory split are you running? Have you tried a different TV/Monitor? Have you tried a different cable? Also, does this occur with either HDMI output? Are you using just one or both? - The more details about your setup the more likely someone will be able to help - as it stands the problem could literally be anything

Comment: I have been using three Rpi4Bs, with 5 different HDMI cables, two Philips HDMI monitors, official and unofficial (QC3.0) PSUs.  Raspbian 10 buster, both Jun26 and Jul10 release recognize my monitors correctly, no need to do any HDMI parameter modification, no "black border" /boot/config.txt modification required (as for Rpi3B+ stretch 9).  I guess your monitor might need to do some HDMI parameter modification.

Comment: The 1080p monitor that I'm using has been successfully used with several Pi-2s and Pi-3s. It's also meaningful to note that when things come up, the picture is beautiful and only degrades into this state after half an hour. This happens on both HDMI ports. I haven't tried a different cable, but it's a real cable and not a cable with a dongle on the end.

Comment: have you tried a different display device (tv/monitor)? the fact that it works with pi2/3 is irrelevant at this stage since the cause of problem isn't yet determined, and you are using a different cable anyway

Comment: @Sander Smith, You remind me a slightly similar HDMI mon troubleshooting experience which is laughable, and happened only once in my work life time. The story went like this.  My monitor started OK but intermittently went blank after 1 to 3 minutes.  I first thought that my old mon was at at end of its life.  But surprisingly I found that my HDMI cable was causing the trouble.  The HDMI cable heats up and temporarily and intermittently breaks, .. I changed the cable and problem disappeared.

Comment: Another possibiltiy is that the Rpi's on board voltage regulator for HDMI detection is not stable, heats up and go crazy after a while. This 5V regulator is for Rpi to detect the HDMI mon's display parameters. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99963/hdmi-power-circuit-on-the-raspberry-pi-4

Comment: @Sander Smith, Rpi4B PCB is hotter than usual, so there is 10% chance the 3V3 to 5V step up regulator (LM2757) heats up and becomes unstable. SUGGESTION: put a (minute!) heat sink on top of the little 3 leg regulator guy (also use a multi-meter to check out if input/output is indeed 3V3 and 5V0 (See the TI app notes for 5V HDMI monitor: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva412a/snva412a.pdf)